# Docker compose not applying cgroup_parent limits

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cgroups

I am trying to impose memory limits on docker containers. In the docker-compose file, I had added this line cgroup_parent: "memory:onetouch.slice". Before this i had created cgroup using cgcreate -g memory:onetouch.slice and set memory.limit_in_bytes to 100MB. When I tried to do memory stress test, cgroup limits are not applied by docker. I tried changing cgroup_parent value to "/onetouch.slice/" and perform memory test. With the updated value it works, OOM kicks in and kills the process which is consuming the memory inside the container. I understand when i specify cgroup_parent with "/" it creates cgroup directly under root.

```
└─onetouch.slice
  └─e0c684625ef3aa074330dd2e84967707ace295d2054a4a5de10c866c5e63afa3
    ├─2584091 bash entrypoint.sh
```

If i don't specify "/" it creates cgroup under containerd.servcie

```
│ ├─containerd.service
│ │ ├─   1162 /usr/bin/containerd
│ │ └─memory:onetouch.slice
│ │   └─fafeaa30c91943ef92b3aca9a462624c0ed1e138446e779c8985da16a41d065c
│ │     ├─1509998 bash entrypoint.sh
```

I want to know the recommended way of setting the cgroup-parent to limit resources of the container (To use "/" or not) and why its not working if i just specify the cgroup name. I am not trying to set limits to individual containers and want to set the limits to group of containers belonging to same profile (Eg.batchjobs) as i want to use the resource effectively as there are spikes in resource usage at times. Also, is there a way to see the maximum memory that can be used from inside the container.